# Bash script to select files to zip/unzip

Tags: bash, shell-script, zip, error-handling

I'm trying to zip and unzip files with a bash script, but I'm new and I have problems. I will explain what the script currently does, and then what I wanted it to do.

- User selects “compress”: a file dialog appears, showing all files.
  The user selects a file (e.g. `/home/ubuntu/file.txt`). The file is
  compressed and saved to `/home/ubuntu` as `file.zip` that contains
  `/home/ubuntu/file.txt`.
- User selects “decompress”: a file dialog appears, showing all files. 
  The user selects a file (e.g. `/home/ubuntu/file.zip`. The file is
  decompressed.

Now what I want from the script to do:

1. After compressing a file, I want the directory of that compressed
   file to be the same. For example, for `/home/ubuntu/filename.txt`, I
   want it to be saved in `/home/ubuntu/` as `filename.zip`. I want it to
   contain only `filename.txt` inside and not `/home/ubuntu/filename.txt`
   or `home/ubuntu/filename.txt`.
2. On decompression, I want the file dialog to show only `*.zip` files,
   so that the user could not select an file this is uncompressed.
3. On decompression, I want to know where the file is saved.

Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
#This bash compresses and decompresses files
act=-1 #A variable used to transfer which action has been  chosen
action1="Compress"  
action2="Decompress"  #action1 & 2 both used for certain echoes

function menu { #The menu
    clear
    local title="-------Menu-------"
    local prompt="Please choose an action:"
    local options=("$action1" "$action2" "Quit")

    echo "$title"
    PS3="$prompt" #Changes the default '#?' that the select command uses to $prompt.
    select option in "${options[@]}";do

        case $option in

            ${options[0]})
            echo "You chose $option"
            act=0 #Changes act to 0 , to be used later      
            break   
            ;;

            ${options[1]})
            echo "You chose $option"
            act=1 #Changes act to 1 , to be used later              
            break;
            ;;
            ${options[2]}) 
            echo "You chose $option"
            exit
            ;;
            *)
            echo "Invalid option please choose between 1-3"
            ;;
        esac
        break
    done
}

function ynPrompt { #a y/n prompt to go back to the main menu or exit
    while true #helps to loop the y/n prompt in case of wrong input ex. a343
    do  

        read -r -p "Do you want to go back to the menu? [y/N] " response
        case $response in

             [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]) #accepts yes or y and ignores casing ex. yEs is accepted.
             continue 2     #continues the outer control loop
             ;;
             [nN][oO]|[nN])     #accepts no or n and ignores casing ex. nO is accepted.     
             exit           #exits the script   
             ;;
             *)
             continue           #shows the message again
            ;;      
        esac
        break
    done
}

function main { #Performs the selected action
    if [ $act -eq 0 ]; then

        if zip -r ${path}.zip ${path}   
        then echo Compression successful
        echo $? #prints 0 
        else echo $? 
        fi


        #echo "$action1"
        #zip -r ${path}.zip ${path}

    elif [ $act -eq 1 ]; then

        if unzip ${path} 
        then echo Decompression successful
        echo ${path}
        echo $? #prints 0
        else echo $?
        fi

        #echo "$action2"
        #unzip ${path}


    else 
        echo "$error"
    fi

}



#~~~~~~~~~~~~ Script start ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
while true #outer control loop
    do
    menu #call menu
    cd /home
    path=$(zenity --file-selection) #Stores the path of the file into path variable through zenity dialog 
#path can only be .zip if i had --file filter *.zip

    if [ -z $path ]; then  #checks length of $path , returns true if length = 0 
        ynPrompt #call ynprompt
    else
        main     #call main
    fi

    break
done
```

Comment: You should describe your problem / question more precisely. It seems to me that your code is not relevant for the task you have described.

Comment: ditto - but since you posted it anyway, just let me say that the few kinds of read prompt programs that aren't 100% annoying would never insist on y/yes/n/no RETURN in a forever loop. just read a byte, compare it to Y/y and abort for anything else. definitely narrow the ok the case, and default to cowardice. its the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for compression:

```
compress_file () 
{
    local dir file
    test -f "$1" || return 2
    dir="$(readlink -f "$1")"
    file="${dir##*/}"
    dir="${dir%/*}"
    cd "$dir"
    # check whether target file exists:
    # test -f "$file".zip && : whatever
    echo zip "$file".zip "$file"
}

compress_file /path/to/file
```

**file selection for decompression**

I am not familiar with `zenity`. It seems that it cannot filter files. You can approach the disired effect by creating a temporary directory, linking only the `*.zip` files into it and run `zenity` for this directory. Of course, if the user selects a different directory then he will see all files.

```
zipfile_dialog () 
{
    local file startdir="/home/ubuntu" tmpdirname=.zipscript.$$
    cd "$startdir" || return 2
    test -d "$tmpdirname" && { rm -r "$tmpdirname" || return 2; }
    mkdir -p "$tmpdirname" || return 2
    for file in *.zip; do
        cd "$tmpdirname"
        ln -s ../"$file"
        cd ..
    done
    ls "$tmpdirname"
    # call zenity here
    rm -r "$tmpdirname"
}

zipfile_dialog
```

An alternative approach would be to use the shell for file selection. That could be done with programmable completion if that is an option for you (`complete`, `compgen`).

Comment: can you add some comments on the code?

Comment: @AlexAndreadis What don't you understand? Seems very simple to me.

Comment: where to use them on my code?? I cant understand.